# Where to select/use the custom template that I created?

Tags: liferay-7

I am using liferay 7 and trying to use my custom template that I created like:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-layout-templates-manually#including-layout-templates-with-a-theme

The question is where can I select this or use this? Is this webcontent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout template defines the layout of a portlet page. The template is selected when you create a new page or edit a page.

[image]

The layout template are not intended to be used in Web content templates. The other place where you can use the layouts is in the *Nested Portlet*.

Comment: I would like to add a div to my page with a custom html. How can I add this to the page? I generated a template but the layout is the same for every page then at the moment.

Comment: This should be probably posted as a new question. Please post a new question and explain more what you want to do. Do you want to add a global section? Do you want to just add a wrapper?